# value error: too many values to unpack , email validation

Tags: python, django

I am trying to give validation to email through forms.py, but it gives me an error of "too many values to unpack" though I am new to django and python programming.

Here is my code:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_base, provider = email.split("@")
    domain, extension = provider.split('.')
    # if not domain == 'USC':
    #   raise forms.ValidationError("Please make sure you use your USC email.")
    if not extension == "edu":
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please use a valid .EDU email address")
    return email
```

Comment: what is your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    extension = provider[::-1].split('.')[0]
    # if not domain == 'USC':
    #   raise forms.ValidationError("Please make sure you use your USC email.")
    if not extension == "ude":
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please use a valid .EDU email address")
    return email
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception, `ValueError: too many values to unpack`, is caused by unpacking a list to unmatchable target variables in terms of the size. For instance,

```
>>> a, b, c = 'xxx.yyy.edu'.split('.')      # ['xxx', 'yyy', 'edu']

# too few target variables
>>> a, b = 'xxx.yyy.edu'.split('.')         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack

# too many target variables
>>> a, b, c, d = 'xxx.yyy.edu'.split('.')   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

In your case, try this,

```
email = 'usrname@xxx.yyy.edu'
email_base, provider = email.split("@")
if 'edu' in provider.split('.'):
    return email
else:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Please use a valid .EDU email address")
```

Comment: This breaks with `.edu.uk`. Returns `uk` as the extension which is wrong

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, thx for pointing out this. I just edited my answer.